# How can I average across sheets defined by an INDIRECT value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 sheets in this sample, each with a value in A1, as follows:

- Sheet1 - A1=18
- Sheet2 - A1=15
- Sheet3 - A1=197
- Sheet4 - A1=534

Then in Sheet5 I have:

- B1='Sheet1
- B2='Sheet4

I want an average of A1 cells from Sheet1 to Sheet4, and I can accomplish this easily with the formula `=AVERAGE(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1)` in Sheet5!A1.

My problem is I want to do that same formula but referencing the sheet values in B1 and B2. I think I need INDIRECT for this, so I tried `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1 & ":" & B2 & "!A1"))`. When I enter that, though, I get a `#REF!` error. What could Excel be failing to reference?

Comment: `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(B1 & ":" & B2 & "!A1"))` double quotes.

Comment: Thanks; I'll edit the question since this gives me a `#REF!` error now.

Comment: is it really `'Sheet4` in B2, with the `'` in front?  If so remove it and change the formula to `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'" & B1 & '":'" & B2 & "'!A1"))`

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan Sir, you are getting `#REF!` error because in the cells `B1` & `B2` the values are `'Sheet1` & `'Sheet2` so  it is not able to identify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula, [**Workbook**](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cgzIatrgZlnYwSGkI?e=HlIf7u)

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'"&"Sheet"&ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"Sheet","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE($B$2,"Sheet","")))&"'!"&CELL("address",A1)))
```

[image: AVERAGE_FROM_MULTIPLE_SHEETS]